# classify with mvnpdf MATLAB

Tags: matlab, classification, bayesian

I am classifying data `xtrain matrix` with `2 features` and `2000 rows` as training, so the dimension is `2`, μ is a 2 element vector and Σ is the covariancxe matrix 2x2:

```
xtrain =
    0.3630    1.6632
   -0.0098    1.8526
   -0.0424    1.6840
   -0.1565    2.1187
    0.5720   -2.7282
   -0.7808    1.1357
    0.5212   -0.6858
    0.1038    1.4735
    ...
```

`mu =
    0.3486    0.8327`

```
sigma =
    1.1163    0.0452
    0.0452    1.5669
```

I am doing something like:

```
mu           = mean(xtrain)
sigma        = cov(xtrain)
% 1/y^2 = (2 pi)^p |\Sigma| exp { (x-\mu)' inv(\Sigma) (x-\mu) }    
p = mvnpdf (xtrain, mu, sigma);
```

then compute:

```
pdfgauss =...
```

The question is How to test the results of the classifier with a `xtest matrix`?

```
I was reading this and it says:

To classify data using Bayesian classifier we already know `Prior(w)` and need to compute `p(x/w)`. When `p` is multidimensioanl Gaussian, we can use Matlab internal function "`mvnpdf`".
```

Example) `mvnpdf(X,Mean,Cov)`

`X <=` data we want to classify
`Mean` <= already known when created
`Cov` <= already known when created

To classify data compute `pdfgauss and multiply by Prior(w)` for each class and choose a class which shows maximum value

To use these functions pdfgauss uses something to compute distances 
`dist = mahalan(X,Mean(:,i),Cov(:,:,i));`

- How do I finish this classification?

pdfgauss.m

```
function y = pdfgauss(X, arg1, arg2 )
% PDFGAUSS Evaluates multivariate Gaussian distribution.
%
% Synopsis:
%  y = pdfgauss(X, Mean, Cov)
%  y = pdfgauss(X, model )
%
% Description:
%  y = pdfgauss(X, Mean, Cov) evaluates a multi-variate Gaussian 
%  probability density function(s) for given input column vectors in X.
%  Mean [dim x ncomp] and Cov [dim x dim x ncomp] describe a set of 
%  ncomp Gaussian distributions to be evaluted such that
%
%  y(i,j) = exp(-0.5(mahalan(X(:,j),Mean(:,i),Cov(:,:,i) )))/norm_const
%
%  where i=1:ncomp and j=1:size(X,2). If the Gaussians are
%  uni-variate then the covariaves can be given as a vector
%  Cov = [Cov_1, Cov_2, ..., Cov_comp].
%
%  y = pdfgauss( X, model ) takes Gaussian parameters from structure
%  fields model.Mean and model.Cov.
%
% Input:
%  X [dim x num_data] Input matrix of column vectors.
%  Mean [dim x ncomp] Means of Gaussians.
%  Cov [dim x dim x ncomp] Covarince matrices.
%
% Output:
%  y [ncomp x num_data] Values of probability density function.
%
% Example:
% 
% Univariate case
%  x = linspace(-5,5,100);
%  y = pdfgauss(x,0,1);
%  figure; plot(x,y)
%
% Multivariate case
%  [Ax,Ay] = meshgrid(linspace(-5,5,100), linspace(-5,5,100));
%  y = pdfgauss([Ax(:)';Ay(:)'],[0;0],[1 0.5; 0.5 1]);
%  figure; surf( Ax, Ay, reshape(y,100,100)); shading interp;
%
% See also 
%  GSAMP, PDFGMM.
%

% About: Statistical Pattern Recognition Toolbox
% (C) 1999-2003, Written by Vojtech Franc and Vaclav Hlavac
% <a href="http://www.cvut.cz">Czech Technical University Prague</a>
% <a href="http://www.feld.cvut.cz">Faculty of Electrical Engineering</a>
% <a href="http://cmp.felk.cvut.cz">Center for Machine Perception</a>

% Modifications:
% 28-apr-2004, VF

% process input arguments
if nargin < 3,
  arg1 = c2s(arg1);
  Mean = arg1.Mean;
  Cov =  arg1.Cov;
else
  Mean = arg1;
  Cov =  arg2;
end

% get dimensions
[dim,num_data] = size(X);
ncomp = size(Mean,2);

% univariate variances can be given as a vector
if size(Cov,1) ~= size(Cov,2), Cov = reshape(Cov,1,1,ncomp); end

% alloc memory
y = zeros(ncomp,num_data);

% evaluate pdf for each component
for i=1:ncomp,
  dist = mahalan(X,Mean(:,i),Cov(:,:,i));
  y(i,:) = exp(-0.5*dist)/sqrt((2*pi)^dim*det(Cov(:,:,i)));
end

return;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't quite understand what are you trying to classify - you have one distribution, one mean, one covariance. If you want to classify, you need kind of function as classifier;

If you had some kind of function

```
[Mean1, Cov1, Mean2, Cov2] = ClassifyInto2Groups
```

then you could calculate the probability for the testX vector to be part of either of the two groups:

```
p_group1 = mvnpdf(testX, Mean1, Cov1)
p_group2 = mvnpdf(testX, Mean2, Cov2)

BelongToGroup = repmat(1, size(testX, 1));
BelongToGroup(p_group2>p_group1) = 2;
```

I write this assuming you want to classify into two groups. If you need just to calculate the probability of testX belonging to the model of trainX, then it's not classification, and you can do it by

```
p = mvnpdf (testX, mu, sigma);
```

I hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer isn't correct (p = mvnpdf (textX, mu, sigma);). This statement returns the probability densities at each point in testX, it doesn't return the actual probabilities.

Comment: This should be a comment on that answer, rather than an answer itself.

Comment: Hey, I know you don't have enough rep to comment yet, but **please** try to avoid writing comments as answers. This is **NOT** an answer